# Two electrons moving along infinite charged sheet

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames

Two electrons move along an infinite charged sheet of positive surface charge density $\sigma$, one at each side, moving with the same velocity $v$, both at a distance $a$ from the sheet.

[image]

The question is for what value of $\sigma$ will the electrons be at a constant distance $2a$ from each other.

I don't really know how to approach this. Since it's special relativity, I thought about going into the electron's frame of refference. Here the electrons are stationary and the sheet is moving to the left, creating surface current. One electron creates electric field pointed away from the sheet of strength
$$E=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_04a^2}$$
at the location of second electron, while the current creates magnetic field perpendicular to the motion of electron of strength
$$B=\frac{1}{2}\mu_0\sigma v$$

This is where I got kinda unsure. I thought I about constructing the electromagnetic field tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ using the electric and magnetic field. Assuming the electrons move in positive $y$ value in the original refference frame and the sheet lies in the $xy$ plane, the EM field tensor looks like this $$F^{\mu\nu}=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&E\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-B\\-E&0&B&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Now contracting this with the four-velocity $U_\nu$ gives us

$$\left(\begin{matrix}-E\gamma v_z\\0\\B\gamma v_z\\\gamma(-E-Bv_y)\end{matrix}\right)$$

Since we want the electrons to be at equalibrium, the force in $z$ direction has to be zero, so we set $$E+Bv_y=0\\
\frac{-q}{16\pi\epsilon_0a^2}=\frac{1}{2}\mu_0\sigma v^2$$

and solving for sigma gives us $$\sigma=\frac{-q}{8\pi\epsilon_0\mu_0a^2v^2}$$

Is this the right way to go about this? I feel that I have made a wrong assumption.

Comment: The B is the same B everywhere? In the original frame the B is zero. I mean the B around the sheet. Putting the zero in to the transformation formula we get:  E'=E*gamma. Which I know to be correct.

Comment: Correct answer is: charge density is proportional to 1/gamma

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought it easier to work in the stationary frame of the charge sheet.

It is easy enough to work out the combined Lorentz force on one electron due to the other. It is just the force between the electrons in their stationary frame, reduced by a factor of $\gamma$. You then just need the charge sheet to have an electric field (the simple electric field of an infinite charge plane) that cancels this force out.